# Different SVG markers for different attributes

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, markers, svg

I am using QGIS 3.0.

I want to use different angle arc SVG markers depending on the data in the attribute table. For example, some points require a 60-degree marker, other a 35-degree marker etc. to give an idea of a field of view from a given point.

Just to clarify, I have 3 different fields of view, depending on the angle view of the photograph. So I want to assign a different angle arc marker depending on the angle specified in the attribute table. `View_angle 62, 30, 20`.

For each I want an arc marker to match the angle.

Comment: How many classes of markers will you need? Do you have a svg-file for each?

Comment: Do you mean different angle for values within one attribute, or between more attributes (fields)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

When you open

> Layer Properties > Symbology > Rule-based

you will be able to apply custom styles to each of your's SVG markers through Rule-based symbology.

In Edit Rule mode, please chose a small icon (Data Defined Override) just on the right side of the Rotation parameter. See the example below.

[image: How_To]

With that, you will get a possibility to define the rotation angle for each feature based on the field value from your attribute table.

References

- [Follow Along: Rule-based Classification](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#hard-fa-rule-based-classification)
- [QGIS: Rotate SVG symbol in layout according with degree number in another layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229810/qgis-rotate-svg-symbol-in-layout-according-with-degree-number-in-another-layer)

Comment: as far as I understood it, the width/arc of the marker is to be set differently, not (only) its orientation.

Comment: I think then you can simply modify the Size, Offset X,Y, or Anchor point parameters, do not you think so [@Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/109646/erik)? Otherwise, create a unique SVG file for each unique feature.

Comment: I thought about using geometry markers, which should be adaptable to unique features of each point.

Comment: [@Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/109646/erik) it makes sense to utilize the geometry generator!