# Individual marker for each map point

Tags: qgis

I'm a newbie with GIS in general and QGIS specifically.  I want to add an individual marker for each point on a layer.  The marker is designed to convey data about the point in a visual manner.  How do I do this?  I have the markers in SVG and PNG formats.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I think it's better to share an example dataset so the answer can be more relatable, it's easier for you to learn that way as well.

Comment: I agree with @ConfusedButterfly, without more information you won't get a better answer than his answer (that is good but probably too generic for a beginner...)

Comment: How many points are there?

Answer (score 2):

If you want each point to have a distinct marker, you need to add attributes for them. After each point has sufficient information, you can use `Symbology -> Rule-based labeling` according to an expression based on your needs.

Read https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html and [Different SVG markers for different attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296113/different-svg-markers-for-different-attributes) for examples.

Comment: If it is just a question of rendering, and each marker should have a different symbol, going to categorize and use $id should be enough.